# getting error in my calendar using "weekly_builder" plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i builed a weekly calendar "weekly_builder" ( https://github.com/dmix/weekly_builder/ ) that i found in http://dmix.ca/2009/06/weeklybuilder-a-weekly-calendar-plugin-for-rails/ .
when i go into the calendar route i get this error:

```
undefined method `starts_at' for #<Status:0x866c100>
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: 
2: <% weekly_links(:date => @date) %>
3: <% weekly_calendar(@events, :date => @date, :include_24_hours => true) do |w| %>
4: <% w.week(:business_hours => params[:business_hours], :clickable_hours => true) do |event,truncate| %>
5: <%= event.date.strftime('%I:%M%p') %>
6: <%= link_to truncate(event.name,truncate), event_path(event) %>
7: <% end %>
```

this is my calendar controller:

```
def weekcalendar
    @date = Time.parse("#{params[:start_date]} || #{Time.now.utc}")
    @start_date = Date.new(@date.year, @date.month, @date.day) 
    @events = Status.find(:all, :conditions => ['date between ? and ?', @start_date,  
    @start_date + 7]) 
end
```

and this is my calendar view:

```
<% weekly_links(:date => @date) %>
<% weekly_calendar(@events, :date => @date, :include_24_hours => true) do |w| %>
<% w.week(:business_hours => params[:business_hours], :clickable_hours => true) do |event,truncate| %>
<%= event.date.strftime('%I:%M%p') %>
<%= link_to truncate(event.name,truncate), event_path(event) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

please let me know what is wrong.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `starts_at` attribute defined for your `Status` model.

According to the error you are getting, there is not `starts_at` defined. Either change the name of whatever attribute you are using to `starts_at`, or in your Status model, define an alias method.

```
alias :starts_at :whatever_field_name
```

or

```
def starts_at
  whatever_field_name
end
```

Or see if there is some configuration parameter with the plugin you are using to specify a different field.

Comment: this is me from anther user, i'm using a :date attribute in the Status model in replace to the stats_at attribute, what i need to change?